# Creating sharepoint 2013 people directory

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I am trying to create a people directory in sharepoint 2013.

So i am trying to add a page of page layout type "(Welcome page)Search People" (reference :  http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/)

But the  item "(Welcome page) Search people" is missing in my page layouts . Also, site pages document library doesnt have a template called page while trying to add new document.

I have configured user profile service app but stil couldnt find the template

Any help on this is appreciated

Regards
Vishnu

Comment: Page layouts are not part of user profile services. You need to activate publishing feature first.

Comment: Hi @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets, I have the exact same problem as vishnu, and i tried what you said : in my search site, i've been "manage site functionnality" and i've seen that "Publication SharePoint Server" is already activated. So what should i do now?Did i miss something? Thanks a lot!